# Unable to give focus to specific fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm validating a simple form with jQuery:

```
$('input:text').blur(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "") {  
    $("#" + $(this).attr("name") + "_error").show();  
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    $(this).focus();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

The `$(this).focus();` doesn't keep the focus on the current field - is there a reason this shouldn't be allowed, or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

I've been playing around with the code a little; when I try to focus a specific field by selecting it by its id, the focus will never remain on the field that the `blur` event was called from; for example if I've got 5 fields, with ids `field1`, `field2`,...`field5`, and have the following code:

```
$('input:text').blur(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "") {  
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    $("#field4").focus();
    return false;  
  }
});
```

if I take the focus away field 1 when it is empty using the tab key, then the focus *is* switched to `#field4`, however, if I tab off field 4 when it is empty, the focus does not remain on field 4, but switches to field 5.  Is this expected / documented behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
setTimeout( $(this).focus(), 500 );
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - however, it hasn't made any difference, and still doesn't achieve what I want...

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you get the event before the input is really blurred.

What happens is:

- User clicks out of the input
- Your method gets called
- The method gives the focus to the input
- The method returns
- The browser propagates the blur event to "itself" and removes the focus

Sudhir's method will work if 500ms is enough time for the browser to finish the event propagation. (But I think this is way enough :) )